# Объект уничтожается раньше, чем вызывается функция этого объекта

Tags: c++, деструктор

Функция создает объект, и возвращает этот объект

```
template< typename nodetype>
List< nodetype > List< nodetype >::concatenate(const List &list1, const List &list2) 
{List <nodetype> concatenateList;
//операции над объектом
return concatenateList;}
```

Деструктор вызывается раньше, чем выполняется операция над объектом

```
concatenateList.concatenate(integerList, integerList2).print();
```

Я ожидал, что сначала будет вызван print(), а потом деструктор.
Как вызвать функцию объекта до удаления? Или лучше избегать создания объекта класса внутри этого же класса?

Comment: А не вызывается ли у вас случаем деструктор у временного объекта, который вы создаете внутри функции `concatenate`, а не у возвращенного? Есть ли у класса `List` надлежащим образом написанные конструкторы копирования / перемещения? И вообще, приведите [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) вместо клочков кода.

Comment: Какие у вас основания так считать? из вашего кода это никак не следует. Тестовый пример наподобие https://ideone.com/GbGBJb демонстрирует, что все нормально работает...

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите тело вашей функции concatenate

Comment: Да, это временный объект, который создается внутри функции. Конструкторов копии и перемещения нет.